# Cisco PIX Port Fort Forwarding

Tags: cisco, cisco-pix

I have the pix running on this network range

192.100.10.0 255.255.255.0

And my server which is on the network

192.200.10.0 255.255.255.0

And my servers IP: 192.200.10.11

I added these commands into the conf of the PIX

```
static (inside,outside) tcp interface 80 192.200.10.11 80 netmask 255.255.255.255
access-list outside-inbound permit tcp any host xx.xx.xx.20 eq 80
```

Where the `xx.xx.xx.20` is my Pix's External IP

I cant seem to access the port from the outside. What am i doing Wrong?

Comment: You say that your PIX is on the network range 192.100.100.0 with a 24 bit netmask. This is inconsistent with your server being on 192.200.10.0 with a 24bit netmask. Misspelled?

Comment: Oh Yea its on this range hang on fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 'interface' needs to be replaced with the external IP.

Comment: That dont work for me it moans about the external interface being the same as the outside interface of the PIX